# AngularJS ng-repeat doesn't work with callback data

Tags: angularjs, socket.io, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a JavaScript function

```
function wantConversation(socket, callback) {
    if(socket)
    {
        socket.emit('user.wantConversation');
    }
    socket.on('user.getConversation', function(data) {
        callback(data);
    });
}
```

it Return a list of Conversations into an array and I call it into my Angular Controller

```
var panel_app = angular.module('panel-app', [])
    .controller('panel-controller', function($scope){
        wantConversation(socket, function(data) {
            $scope.conversations = data;
        });
    };
});
```

But my ng-repeat doesn't work :(  i know problem is callback function.
and this is my Html

```
<div ng-repeat="x in conversations | filter: searchBox">
    {{ x.name }}
    // ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell angular when the scope is modified outside of angular context so it can run a digest cycle to update view

Try

```
wantConversation(socket, function(data) {
    $scope.conversations = data;
    $scope.$apply();// tell angular to update view
});
```

Comment: Important to realize that `socket` isn't part of angular